# How to display an Array of Objects in a table using ngFor?

Tags: html, angular6, ngfor

I am attempting to display some results I gather in a table. I know to use `ngFor` or at least that is what my research has shown me.

I have attempted using the `keyvalue` method mentioned in other posts, but this still does not render any results. I am thinking this is a super simple issue, I am just missing a small component.

So I create a an `[Object Array]` called `userResults` that looks something like

```
[
{key: 'example@example.com', value: 'message'}
]
```

It is created in my results component which looks something like:

```
@Component(
{
    selector: 'app-results',
    templateUrl: './results.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./results.component.css'],
    providers: [ApiService, DataService]
})
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(private _apiService: ApiService, private router: Router, private _dataService: DataService)
    {
        this.userResults = this._dataService.getData();
    }
displayedColumns: string[] = ['User Email', 'Result'];
userResults = [];
employeeCheck(user: string)
    {
        console.log('Completing employee check')

        if (this)
        { 
            this.userResults.push({
                key: user,
                value:  this.messages[3];
            });
            this.createTable();
        }
        else if (this)
        { //Check that NGP exists and is valid
            this.userResults.push({
                key: user,
                value:  this.messages[4];
            });
            this.createTable();
        }
        else if (this)
        { 
            this.userResults.push({
                key: user,
                value:  this.messages[6]
            });
            this.createTable();
        }

        else if (this)
        { 
            this.userResults.push({
                key: user,
                value:  this.messages[5]
            });
            this.createTable();
        }
        else
        { //Don't know what else to do
            this.userResults.push({
                key: user,
                value:  this.messages[7]
            });
            console.log(this.userResults[0].key)
            this._dataService.saveResults(this.userResults);
            this.createTable();
        }
//console.log(this.userResults);

    }


    userCheck(user: string)
    {
        console.log('Checking ', user, ' information.');

        if (this)
        {
            this.userResults.push({
                key: user,
                value:  this.messages[0]
            });
            this.createTable();
        }
        else if (this)
        {
            this.userResults.push({
                key: user,
                value:  this.messages[1]
            });
            this.createTable();
        }
        else if (this)
        {
            this.userResults.push({
                key: user,
                value:  this.messages[2];
            });
            this.createTable();
        }
        else
        {
            this.employeeCheck(user);
        }
    }
createTable()
    {
        console.log(this.userResults)
        console.log('going to results')
        this.router.navigate(['/results'])      
    }
```

my service looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, throwError} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class DataService {
    private results: any[];
    constructor() { }

    saveResults(someArray){
        console.log('saving results')
        this.results = someArray
        console.log(this.results)
    }


}
```

I create this object by going through a series of if/else statements in a different function adding values as needed to the objct. At the end of that function, I navigate to the `/results` page and the html for that page looks like:

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center">
  <br />
  <h1>Results</h1>

  <head>
    <style>
      table,
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width:50%" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
          {{ col }}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of userResults | keyvalue">
        <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

I am trying to get a table that looks something like

```
|       User Email       |       Result       |
|  example@example.com   |       message      |
```

as of now I am only getting the Column names to display. Like I said before, I have referred to other posts about this topic. I am following the suggestions mentioned there, but it is still not working. I think there is a small, but pivotal piece I am forgetting. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you edited the title to "display an Object" but in your question you are trying to "display Array of Objects". so which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyvalue` pipe is used to iterate over objects not arrays. iterating an array with `*ngFor` doesn't require any additional structure.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of userResults">
  <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
</tr>
```

should be enough, where `userResults` is similar to this

```
userResults = [
  {key:"example1@example.com", value: "message1"},
  {key:"example2@example.com", value: "message2"}
]
```

one more thing is that; `head` `body` and `style` tags shouldn't be used in angular templates. and you should place your `css` styles either in your `component.ts` file as inline styles

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-my",
  templateUrl: "./my.component.html",
  styles: [
    `
      table,
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        align: center;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

or in a seperate file called `component.css` and add that file should be referenced in your component.ts file

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-my",
  templateUrl: "./my.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my.component.css"]
})
export class MyComponent {}
```